# Regular Expression in exactly this form : Tyler Durden

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi i need a javascript regex for a name field in my html form. The user should be able to enter multiple names seperated with space. And first character of all names should be a capital. No numbers, special chars. etc.

thank you.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: First rule of Javascript: don't talk about Javascript!

Comment: So names such as "de la Rue " are banned

Comment: Names like O'Reilly and Woodward-Court would also be banned

Comment: Middle initials would be banned too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]* [A-Z][a-zA-Z]*$
```

if need more than two names:

```
^([A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)( [A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)*$
```

Comment: This only matches two names. OP needs multiple names.

Comment: Multiple names need to be separated by a space. Marking with spaces would be more appropriate.

Comment: And what about names in non-Latin alphabets, or ones containing apostrophes (e.g. O'Relly)

Comment: ^([A-ZА-Я]['a-zа-яA-ZА-Я]*)( [A-ZА-Я]['a-zа-яA-ZА-Я]*)*$   ?)

Answer (score 1):

```
\b([A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*)\b
```

`\b` matches a word boundarym with 0 width.

Answer (score 0):

`^([A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*)*`

will match the following strings and capture them into groups like so:

`Tyler Durden something else John Doe another thing Barack Obama`

`Tyler Durden` `John Doe` `Barack Obama`

Comment: "123Tyler Durden123" will pass this regex. Use ^ and $

Answer (score 0):

```
var nameOne = "Tyler Durden";
nameOne.match(/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*(\s+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)*$/);
>>> [ "Tyler Durden", " Durden" ]

var nameTwo = "Tyler Francis Durden";
nameTwo.match(/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*(\s+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)*$/);
>>> ["Tyler Francis Durden", " Durden"]
```

Because of the parenthesis defining a capturing group you get the final name as a captured match. To get the whole name if it matches, use

```
nameTwo.match(/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*(\s+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)*$/)[0];
>>> "Tyler Francis Durden"
```

If you only care about matched vs unmatched, you can just test the return for `null`

Answer (score -1):

```
^([A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*)(:b+[A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*)*$
```

You can use more than one space to separate each name. This is if you interpret being able to give "multiple names" as meaning a single name is a combination of the first and the last name.

This should match multiple names like this:

Bill Smith

or

Bill Smith Brian Jones Allan King

Comment: editor was eating my characters before.. added the code section